# Strange issue with a datagridview and a tabcontrol C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a strange problem. I have a `TabControl` with two `TabPages`. Each page has a `datagridview`. Both `datagridviews` are populated with `XML` files.

I want to have the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` set to "`Fill`" for both `DataGridViews`. I want to set the width of columns in my code.

And everything works fine for the `TabPage1` but setting width for the `DataGridView` on `TabPage2` throws the `NullReferenceException`.

I really don't get it because I do the same thing as for `datagridview1` and there works fine but `datagridview2` throws the exception. Additionally, there is no exception if I choose any `AutoSizeColumnsMode` value but `Fill`.

Here's the code:

```
        XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("File1.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);



            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

           dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 35;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 248;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 110;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 140;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Width = 127;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 100;

            xmlFile.Close();

        XmlReader xmlFile2= XmlReader.Create("File2.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ds2.ReadXml(xmlFile2);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];


            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Width = 135; // The exception is thrown here
            dataGridView2.Columns[9].Width = 200;
            dataGridView2.Columns[8].Width = 300;
            dataGridView2.Columns[7].Width = 70;
            dataGridView2.Columns[6].Width = 70;
            dataGridView2.Columns[5].Width = 124;
            dataGridView2.Columns[4].Width = 81;
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Width = 70;
            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Width = 70;
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = 124;

            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Visible = true;
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Visible = true;

            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Visible = true;
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = true;
            dataGridView2.Columns[4].Visible = true;

            dataGridView2.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.Columns[7].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.Columns[9].Visible = false;


            xmlFile2.Close();
```

Comment: That implies that the column doesn't exist. Are you getting data back from `File2.xml`? In other words, does ds2 actually contain the loaded data?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting data back from File2.xml. The problem is when I try to change the widths of columns. Even changing visibility works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a data-bound control(`dataGridView2`) is not updated until the control is made visible. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/70f0bbbb-07d5-4253-9a79-789700a8450a). You can refresh the binding, for example, by programmatically switching to `TabPage2` and back to the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

THe only thing I can se at the moment is that you are not doing this on tabpage 2

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

try

```
dataGridView2.Sort(dataGridView2.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: It's not important and has no meaning.